# Convert csv to txt in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm very new in python and I'm trying to convert csv file into txt file. In my csv file I have 15.000 rows and 30 cols.

Is there any simple way, how to do that in python?

Comment: Read https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html, and you will get all what you need. `csv` module is a built-in module and is easy to use.

Comment: This is primarily opinion based. Have you done any research yourself so far?

Comment: What kind of conversion? You mean other than just changing the file extension to `.txt` ?

Comment: Additionally, it is unclear what you are asking

Comment: CSV is essentially text file separated by comma.

Comment: When I try to change file extension to txt I'm getting comma delimited col header but there are ,,,,,,,,, comas between data.

Comment: @martinkabe So what do you want to do? Remove all commas? remove some of the commas? What are you trying to end up with?

Comment: Well, I need to remove all the commas to have only space separator. It seems to comma makes a lot of issues.

Comment: @martinkabe That is information that should have been in your question.

Answer (score -2):

```
Import xlrd
```

Then read xlrd doc and write out cells to txt-file